# Subset matrix using vector of indices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have some problem trying to understand a code. I have a code which supposedly loads in a matrix and calls the top `n` features in a columns as below.

```
TopFeatures <- function(matrix, ncols = 1, nfeatures = 20){
   mtx <- matrix[ , ncols, drop = FALSE]
   data <- mtx[order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
   features <- head(x = rownames(x = data), n = nfeatures
   return(features)
}
```

However, whenever I try it for number of columns more than 1, I get an error as below.

```
> TopFeatures(so, ncols = 1:3, nfeatures = 10)
Error in mtx[order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I believe the error comes from this line:

```
data <- mtx[order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
```

However, I don't really understand what this line is supposed to do.

My understanding is that the purpose here is to rank all the cells in the matrix and then sort them in decreasing order, then pick out the top `n` features. The function `order` sorts your matrix and return a vector of indices equal to the number of cells in the matrix, but you cannot subset using the vector of indices because the number will exceed the number of row. I guess that's why I have this error. However, I have no idea how to fix this.

Could someone please guide me how to resolve this issue?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should `order` based on only one column. Hence, when you have one column it works but it doesn't work when you have more than one column.

Assuming the first column is the one you want to `order` your data, you can try :

```
TopFeatures <- function(matrix, ncols = 1, nfeatures = 20){
   mtx <- matrix[ , ncols, drop = FALSE]
   data <- mtx[order(mtx[, 1], decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
   features <- head(x = rownames(data), n = nfeatures)
   return(features)
}
```

---

In this line

```
mtx[order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
```

you are trying to arrange rows based on values in `mtx` matrix.

So let's say you have a one-column matrix.

```
mtx <- matrix(1:10)
data <- mtx[order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE] #gives
data

#      [,1]
# [1,]   10
# [2,]    9
# [3,]    8
# [4,]    7
# [5,]    6
# [6,]    5
# [7,]    4
# [8,]    3
# [9,]    2
#[10,]    1
```

whereas with 2-column matrix, you get :

```
mtx <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
data <- mtx[order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]
```

> Error in mtx[order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE] : 
>     subscript out of bounds

i.e because

```
order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE) #returns
#[1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

but you have only 5 rows in the data, hence the error.

If you `order` by only 1st column you get

```
order(mtx[, 1], decreasing = TRUE)
#[1] 5 4 3 2 1
```

which will not give you an error on subsetting.

Comment: Yes, I know it works with one column. But I think the original script intends to sort the entire matrix and not only using 1 column. _p.s. All values in the matrix are numerical._

Comment: Yes, thank you. I understand your explanation. But the script was written that way initially & was claimed to work. So I don't know where's the mistake as I'm not sure if they wanted to arrange it on the 1st column only.

Anyway, do you have any idea how to order an entire matrix - meaning all values in the matrix then sort them & return them as a matrix again? I mean, a matrix is essentially a vector with dimensions, so I assumed you could sort all values in the matrix. No? Please correct me if I'm mistaken. 

Thank you for your prompt reply!!!

Comment: If you want to `order` the entire matrix I don't understand why anyone would use this line `mtx[order(mtx, decreasing = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]`. Can you please confirm what are you are trying to achieve probably better with an example and show expected output. If none of us know what we are trying to achieve and we are just shooting in the dark, then I'll probably delete the answer.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't give an example because it's not my script in the first place. But I assumed it's something like this:

Comment: I'm simplifying it for explanation's sake, but this matrix is a huge matrix of cell vs gene and the values in the matrix are expression values. So, assuming you have a matrix as such: `mat(c(1,5,-11,0), nrow = 2`, then arrange all the cells in the matrix so that the order would be `5, 1, 0, -11` and then extract the row names of those cells.

Comment: I hope my explanation is clear. I've tried to post the problem in the developer's website but no response so far. Therefore I am trying to re-write the script myself. Could you suggest any way that I could re-order the entire matrix?

Comment: In summary, what I want to achieve is to arrange all cells in the matrix in an order, and then extract the row names of the, say, top 50 cells.

Comment: If you have matrix-like `mat <- matrix(c(1,5,-11,0), nrow = 2)`, you can do `mat[] <- sort(mat, decreasing = TRUE)` to sort and then extract rownames of top `n` rows like `rownames(mat)[1:n]` ?

Comment: Thanks Ronak for your feedback and explanation! I managed to solve this by flattening the matrix with `gdata::unmatrix(mat)` then ordering it with `mat[order(mat, decreasing = TRUE)]` and extract the top `n` features using `names(head(x = mat, n = 50))`. Thanks again for your time & explanation. Cheers!